# Не закрывается алерт с первого клика (андроид)

Tags: android, kotlin

Алерт не закрывается с первого клика по кнопке <ок>. А только после второго клика.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun FirstFragment.alertDateAfterAll(): Boolean {
    if (dataStartSid.isAfter(dataIsk) || dataStartSid.isAfter(dataString3parse)) {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        with(dialogBuilder) {
            setIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
            setTitle("Проверьте даты!")
            setCancelable(false)
            setNegativeButton("Ок", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
            })
            show()
        }
        return false
    }
    else
        return true
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun FirstFragment.resumeSidAll() {
    datesCreate()
    alertDateAfterAll()
    if (alertDateAfterAll()) {
        val srokSid = Period.of(3, 0, 0)
        val dateEndSid = dataStartSid.plus(srokSid)
        outDataSid.text = dateEndSid.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")).toString()
        val d5razn = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dataString3parse, 
        ................
        val d5raznPer = Period.between(dataString3parse, dataString4parse.plusDays(1))
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Срок удлинился на " + d5raznPer.months + " мес. и " + d5raznPer.days + " дн.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас два диалога одинаковых открываются, 3 и 4 строки метода `resumeSidAll`

Comment: спасибо, то есть вторую строку надо убрать из `resumeSidAll` . Оказывается проверка функции на if - вызывает также её выполнение!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex_Skvortsov подсказал ответ

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun FirstFragment.resumeSidAll() {
    datesCreate()
Убрать >>> alertDateAfterAll() <<< 
    if (alertDateAfterAll()) {
        val srokSid = Period.of(3, 0, 0)
        val dateEndSid = dataStartSid.plus(srokSid)
        outDataSid.text = dateEndSid.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")).toString()
        val d5razn = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dataString3parse, 
        ................
        val d5raznPer = Period.between(dataString3parse, dataString4parse.plusDays(1))
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Срок удлинился на " + d5raznPer.months + " мес. и " + d5raznPer.days + " дн.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```